# Load Python Pandas data into SQL Server, conversion from variable or parameter type INT to target column type BIGINT is not supported

Tags: sql-server, pandas, dataframe, bigint, pypyodbc

I am trying to load a Python Pandas dataset into an existing table in SQL Server database.

In SQL Server, the table contains three columns and types are below:

```
[account] [bigint] NULL,
[info] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[start_date] [datetime] NULL
```

And this is my Pandas data:

```
    account int64
    info object
    start_date datimetime64[ns]
```

When I was trying to run Python like:

```
for index, row in combined_df.iterrows():
    values = (row.account, row.info, row.start_date)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table "
                   "(account, info, start_date "
                    "values(?, ?, ?)",
                    values
                    )
```

I get an error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion from variable or parameter type INT to target column type BIGINT is not supported. (102044) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Any ideas? I tried to convert the type to other ones but could not find any solution. Please give a help, many thanks!